# Finding values of $x$ and $y$ such that $\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}+x}=3\sqrt{5}+y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So the question is this:

> Find values of $x$ and $y$ such that:
> $$\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}+x}=3\sqrt{5}+y$$

I'm immediately confused, because this expression can be graphed - suggesting there's many valid pairs of values for $x$ and $y$. For example, if I assume $x=0$, then I can produce an expression for the value of $y$.  But I don't *think* that is what is wanted.

**Attempts**

We've spent more hours than I'd like to admit just manipulating this expression in the hope something would drop out.  The "best" ideas where

- Multiplying the LHS by $\frac{\sqrt{5}-x}{\sqrt{5}-x}$ to get surds out of the denominator but that generates an $x^2$ term, and can't see any obvious route from there.
- Multiplying both sides by $\sqrt{5}+x$, and the multiplying out the brackets on the RHS, but that generates an $xy$ term - no idea how to then pick that apart.

For context this is my son's (16yo) pre-A-level work, and it's in the surds section.  I suspect there's a specific surd rule/manipulation that I don't know.  I'd be very grateful if someone can point us in the right direction.

**Deep background (possibly irrelevant!)**

This was the last question of many - and frustratingly the only one we couldn't eventually figure out.  The penultimate question is pretty similar and I suspect we're supposed to use similar techniques (which is why I've included it here.)

Again find x and y but this time such that $\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}+1}=x\sqrt{5}+y$

We multiplied the LHS by $\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{5}-1}$ to give $\frac{2(\sqrt{5}-1)}{(\sqrt{5}+1)(\sqrt{5}-1)}=x\sqrt{5}+y$

Simplified to $\frac{2(\sqrt{5}-1)}{4}=x\sqrt{5}+y$

And then to $\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}=x\sqrt{5}+y$

And then to $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{5}-\frac{1}{2}=x\sqrt{5}+y$

Hence we answer that $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and $y=-\frac{1}{2}$.  That feels like the answer being requested, even though it seems that multiple $(x,y)$ pairs could have been provided.  Anyway, the key here was to get x and y on the RHS and then have the LHS look similar.  We've been unable to achieve that with the problem question though.

**Update 1**

Below is a graph of the equation at the top of the post, courtesy of the excellent desmos.com.

[image: This is a graph of the equation, courtesy of the excellent desmos.com]

Comment: Yes, giving $x$ some value and solving for the corresponding $y$ that satisfies the equation will produce many pairs. The set of points $(x,y)$ with real valued coordinates $x,y$ that satisfy the first equation is a hyperbola. Many points.

Comment: Great - I'm not going crazy then!  But if you cast your eye at the background section I wrote, it seems there's probably a more aesthetically pleasing pair of x and y values that I'm supposed to find.  Is there a way to progress on that?

Comment: The problem could have asked for rational, or integer solutions. If you write the equation as $3=(3\sqrt{5}+y)(\sqrt{5}+x)=\sqrt{5}(y+3x) + (15+xy)$ and take into account that $\sqrt{5}$ is not rational, then $y=3x$ and $3=15+xy$. Using $y=3x$ to eliminate the $y$ in $3=15+xy$, we get $3=15-3x^2$, or $x^2=4$. This has the two solutions $x=-2$ and $x=2$, with corresponding $y=6$ and $y=-6$. They did not ask, though.

Comment: That's really helpful thank you @NDB.  As you said, (-2, 6) and (2, -6) are indeed both points on the graph.  And I get your logic about $y=3x$.  Can you promote your comment to an answer - is that a thing?

Comment: I think you meant $y=-3x$.

Comment: Maybe there is a nice [parametrization](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParametricEquations.html) $x=f(t),y=g(t)$

Comment: Thank you @TymaGaidash, I'm sure you're right, but I think it's a bit beyond me to find those!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer was kindly provided by @NDB in the comments.  If they want to copy/paste/edit this answer into their own name I will happily delete this answer - but I don't want to leave the question unanswered.

Crucially this answer imagines that the question asked for a pair of integer points that satisfy the equation.

Here are the steps:

$\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}+x}=3\sqrt{5}+y$

Multiple both sides by $\sqrt{5}+x$

$3=(\sqrt{5}+x)*(3\sqrt{5}+y)$

Multiply out the brackets

$3=15+3x\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{5}y+xy$

Subtract 15 from both sides, and then factor out the $\sqrt{5}$

$-12 = \sqrt{5}(3x + y) + xy$

Clever bit, is to realise that in order to get an integer result, the $\sqrt{5}(3x+y)$ must be zero, so

$-12 = xy$ and $y=-3x$

Substituting the later equation into the first

$-12 = x(-3x)$

$4 = x^2$

$x = 2$ or $x=-2$

And since $y=-3x$, we get the points $(2,-6)$ and ${-2, 6}$